# Генрі чи Хенрі?

Tags: вживання-слів, from-english, власні-назви, іноземні-імена

Дуже часто імена жителів інших країн перекладають українською з першою літерою Г, на місці якої, на мою думку, мала би бути Х. Яскравий приклад - Генрі/Хенрі. То як правильно?

Comment: Див. також: [«Правила вживання літери г/ґ/х при запозиченні іншомовних слів на g/h (гакер, гостинг)»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/347).

Comment: Nepohano pidkryplüvaty čymosj _na moü dumku_.

Answer (score 0):

«Прапопис» 2015 року ([§ 87](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87)) каже:

> **G** і **h** звичайно передаються літерою **г**: *аванга́рд*, *агіта́ція*, *агре́сор*, *гва́рдія*, *гене́тика*, *гімна́стика*, *гоніо́метр*, *грандіо́зний*, *гра́фік*, *грог*, *емба́рго*, *лінгві́стика*, *мігра́ція*; *гандбо́л*, *гегемо́нія*, *гекта́р*, *герба́рій*, *ге́рцог*, *гі́нді* (мова), *гіпо́теза*, *горизо́нт*, *го́спіталь*, *гугено́т*, *гу́мус*; *Гаа́га*, *Гава́на*, *Гавр*, *Га́рвард*, *Гаро́нна*, *Гвіне́я*, *Гельсінгфо́рс*, *Ге́льсінкі*, *Гіндуста́н*, *Гренла́ндія*, *Гре́ція*, *Йога́ннесбург*, *Люксембу́рг*; *Ганніба́л*, *Ге́йне*, *Ге́те*, *Гізо́*, *Гоме́р*, *Гора́цій*, *Горн*, *Гюго́*, *Магоме́т*.
>
> В окремих словах англійського походження **h** передається літерою **х**: *хо́бі, хоке́й, хол; Хемінгуе́й* та ін.

Тобто в загальному випадку перевага надається літері «**г**». (Літера «**х**» застосовується здебільшого у випадках, коли з якихось причин уже зафіксувалися вимова й написання з «х».)